# xml merging with Lua script

Tags: lua

I have one task... of course I am not expecting you people to give me ready-made solution, but some outline will be very much helpful. Please help, as Lua is a new language for me.
So the task is:

1. I have three xml files. All the xml files are storing the data about the same objects say equipment. Except the name of the equipment, the parameters, xmls storing are different.
2. Now I want to make a generic xml file, which is carrying all the data(all parameters) about the equipment.
3. Please note that, the name will be unique and thus it will act as a key parameter.
4. I want to achieve this task with Lua script.

Comment: Have you made a start already? If so, can you post it here as well?

Comment: yes, Bart I have started it, my approach was first to read file and save that in a string and then to search for the name- a unique key in all three strings, but I found it wrong.I think the approach should be something like Parsing in Java, so that we can create objects, we can combine the attributes of that object and then recreate the final xml. But I am not aware of XML parsing through Lua.

Comment: Hmm, a quick search on "Lua XML parsing" got me quite some results back. Like I suggested before: better post your attempts here and ask specific question(s) about the code you're working on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Lua does not do xml "by default". It is a language thought to be "embedded" into other systems, so it could happen that the system you have it "embedded in" is able to parse the xml files and pass them on to Lua. If that's the case, translate the xmls to Lua tables on the host system, then give them to Lua, manipulate them, in Lua, and return the resulting Lua table, so that the host can transform it to xml.

Another option, if available, would be installing a binary library for parsing xml, such as [luaxml](http://viremo.eludi.net/LuaXML/). If you are able to install it in your system, you should be able to manipulate the xml files more or less easily directly from Lua. But this possibility depends on the system you have embedded Lua into; a lot of systems don't allow installation of additional libraries.